# How to generate Date Series in HIVE? (Creating table)

Tags: hadoop, hive

Suppose I currently have a table that has 1 row for each account and the data in the tables are:

1. Account Number
2. Start Date
3. End Date

Now I'd like to create a new table that has 1 row for each day the account is open, i.e. 1 day for each row between the start and end dates (inclusive) for each account.

E.g.

**Table 1**

```
Account Number    Start Date    End Date
123               1-Jan-17      1-Jul-17
456               1-Feb-17      4-May-17
```

**Table 2** (Desired table)

```
Account Number    Day
123               1-Jan-17
123               1-Jan-17
     ...
123               1-Jul-17
456               1-Feb-17
456               2-Feb-17
     ...
456               4-May-17
```

I know in Postgresql there's a function called 'generate series' that would allow you to do that easily. I'm wondering if there's a similar function in HIVE that would allow you to do that as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the `DATE` data type to store dates and the ISO FORMAT `YYYY-MM-DD` for a textual representation of dates

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
select  t.AccountNumber
       ,date_add (t.StartDate,pe.i)   as Day

from    Table1 t
        lateral view 
        posexplode(split(space(datediff(t.EndDate,t.StartDate)),' ')) pe as i,x
```

Comment: Works like a charm! . Thanks! :)

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz thanks for the solution. I am looking for a similar result but instead of day series, I am looking for month series where in I should get a row for each month and a new column which generates the enddate for each month. Appreciate your help

Comment: Hi. Please open a new question for this. If no one will answer within couple of days I will answer it.

Comment: create temporary TABLE tmp_getdate as
select cast(date_hive as date) data_date
from generate_series((date_trunc('Month',idate))::Date,idate,'1 day'::interval) date;   -- please help me