# HIVE: Replace empty results by 0 in group by statements

Tags: hive, aggregate-functions

I'm a new Hive user, and need to aggregate the sum of amounts for a given table. Consider the simplified example below:

```
SELECT day, sum(amount) FROM tableX WHERE columnA = 'RareValue' GROUP BY day;
```

Suppose that it's possible that there is no row entry which matches the condition in the `WHERE` clause for some dates. And so the query result will skip those days.

For example, this is the result I get:

```
date       amount
2018-01-15 230
2018-01-13 210
2018-01-12 140
2018-01-11 222
```

But this is the desired result:

```
date       amount
2018-01-15 230
2018-01-14 0
2018-01-13 210
2018-01-12 140
2018-01-11 222
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45279528/4862402) to generate a sequence of dates and then use `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE` to fill empty dates by zeros. However, the performance was terrible slow. What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you are trying to exclude the whole day in case when your where condition is true, you can do something like

```
select 
day,
if(max(mycondition) = 0, sum(amount), 0) as mysum from 
(
select day, amount, 
if(columnA = 'RareValue', 1, 0) as mycondition
FROM tableX 
) t GROUP BY day;
```

I did not have the chance to test it :)

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood you all needed days are presented in tableX table. So, I advise first select all rows where columnA is not equal 'RareValue' and that UNION it with your query.

```
SELECT day, 0 FROM tableX WHERE columnA != 'RareValue'
UNION
SELECT day,sum(amount) from tableX WHERE columnA = 'RareValue' GROUP BY day;
```

> if the days from the first select repeats you can add 'distinct'