# Efficient Date Case Logic in Hive

Tags: datetime, hive, hiveql

I have a 65M~ record table in Hive that contains patient, facility, service start and service end dates. The table looks similar to the MWE below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE <your_db>.example
(accountId string,
 provider string,
 startdate timestamp,
 enddate timestamp);

INSERT INTO TABLE <your_db>.example VALUES
('123A', 'smith', '2019-03-01 00:00:00', '2019-03-04 00:00:00'),
('456B', 'rogers', '2019-03-02 00:00:00', '2019-03-03 00:00:00'),
('123A', 'smith', '2019-03-03 00:00:00', '2019-03-06 00:00:00'),
('123A', 'smith', '2019-03-07 00:00:00', '2019-03-08 00:00:00'),
('456B', 'daniels', '2019-03-04 00:00:00', '2019-03-05 00:00:00'),
('456B', 'daniels', '2019-03-06 00:00:00', '2019-03-09 00:00:00'),
('123A', 'smith', '2019-03-10 00:00:00', '2019-03-12 00:00:00');


SELECT * FROM <your_db>.example;
#   example.accountid  example.provider example.startdate       example.enddate
#1  123A               smith            2019-03-01 00:00:00.0   2019-03-04 00:00:00.0
#2  456B               rogers           2019-03-02 00:00:00.0   2019-03-03 00:00:00.0
#3  123A               smith            2019-03-03 00:00:00.0   2019-03-06 00:00:00.0
#4  123A               smith            2019-03-07 00:00:00.0   2019-03-08 00:00:00.0
#5  456B               daniels          2019-03-04 00:00:00.0   2019-03-05 00:00:00.0
#6  456B               daniels          2019-03-06 00:00:00.0   2019-03-09 00:00:00.0
#7  123A               smith            2019-03-10 00:00:00.0   2019-03-12 00:00:00.0
```

I want to define the continuous `startdate` and `enddate` for `accountId` and `provider` combination, where there is no more than 1 day between a record's `enddate` and the next record's `startdate`, then calculate the number of days in the continuous block (called "los" for length-of-stay). This grouping is called a "case". Below is what the case output needs to look like:

```sql
#   results.accountid  results.provider results.los results.startdate       results.enddate
#1  123A               smith            7           2019-03-01 00:00:00.0   2019-03-08 00:00:00.0
#2  456B               rogers           1           2019-03-02 00:00:00.0   2019-03-03 00:00:00.0
#3  456B               daniels          5           2019-03-04 00:00:00.0   2019-03-09 00:00:00.0
#4  123A               smith            2           2019-03-10 00:00:00.0   2019-03-12 00:00:00.0
```

We are currently using the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45278300/how-to-generate-date-series-in-hive-creating-table), but it becomes a very expensive operation with our actual (65M record) table. I'm thinking that a more efficient solution would be to first consolidate and define each cases' `startdate` and `enddate`, and then run a `datediff` calculation (instead of exploding each date range), but I'm not sure how to pull that off in HiveQL.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is data correct in your table for third row as same accountid is active for two different dates #3  123A               smith            2019-03-03 00:00:00.0   2019-03-06 00:00:00.0
. I mean they have different start dates? Just asking

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Digging through our company's repos, I found the creative solution below that does what we're looking for. Have yet to test out its performance improvement over the current 'explode' solution. It does what I asked for in the original question, but it is a bit complex (though well commented).

```sql
/*
STEP 1: Input
*/

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS <your_db>.tmp_completedatepairs;

CREATE TABLE AS <your_db>.tmp_completedatepairs AS
SELECT CONCAT(isnull(accountid, ''), "-", isnull(provider, '')) AS tag
     , startdate
     , enddate
  FROM <your_db>.example
 WHERE startdate IS NOT NULL 
       AND enddate IS NOT NULL;

/*
STEP 2: Create new pairs of start and end dates that are 
better time span tiles across the stay period 
*/

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS <your_db>.tmp_respaned_input;

CREATE TABLE <your_db>.tmp_respaned_input AS
SELECT SD.tag
     , SD.startdate
     , ED.enddate
  FROM (SELECT *
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tag ORDER BY startdate ASC) AS rnsd
          FROM <your_db>.tmp_completedatepairs) AS SD
       LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT *
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tag ORDER BY enddate ASC) AS rned
          FROM <your_db>.tmp_completedatepairs) AS ED
       ON SD.tag=ED.tag
          AND SD.rnsd=ED.rned;

/*
STEP 3: Find gaps >1day and define stays around them
This consists of several substeps:
(a) Isolate all start dates that are more than 1 day after a preceding start date with the same tag, or are the earliest date for the tag. Number them in order.
(b) Isolate all end dates that are more than 1 day before a following end date with the same tag, or are the last date for the tag. Number them in order.
(c) Match together corresponding start and end dates after SELECTing only those dates that terminate a case (rather than dates that occur within case boundaries)
*/

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS <your_db>.results;

CREATE TABLE <your_db>.resuts AS
-- (c) Match together corresponding start and end dates after SELECTing only those dates that terminate a case (rather than dates that occur within case boundaries)
SELECT SPLIT(tag,'-')[0] AS accountid
     , SPLIT(tag,'-')[1] AS provider
     , DATEDIFF(enddate, startdate) AS los
     , startdate
     , enddate
  FROM
       -- (a) Isolate all start dates that are more than 1 day after a preceding end date with the same tag, or are the earliest date for the tag. Number them in order.
       (SELECT tag
             , startdate
             , CONCAT(tag, CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tag ORDER BY startdate ASC) AS string)) AS rnlink
          FROM (SELECT L.tag
                     , L.startdate AS startdate
                     , DATEDIFF(L.startdate, R.enddate) AS d
                  FROM (SELECT *
                             , CONCAT(tag, CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tag ORDER BY startdate ASC) AS string)) AS rnstart
                          FROM <your_db>.tmp_respaned_input) L
                       LEFT JOIN
                       (SELECT *
                             , CONCAT(tag, CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tag ORDER BY enddate ASC) + 1 AS string)) AS rnstart
                          FROM <your_db>.tmp_respaned_input) R
                       ON L.rnstart = R.rnstart) X
         WHERE d > 1 OR d IS NULL) S

       LEFT JOIN
       -- (b) Isolate all end dates that are more than 1 day before a following start date with the same tag, or are the last date for the tag. Number them in order.
       (SELECT  enddate
             , CONCAT(tag, CAST(row_number() over (PARTITION BY tag ORDER BY enddate ASC) AS string)) AS rnlink
          FROM (SELECT L.tag
                     , L.enddate AS enddate
                     , DATEDIFF(R.startdate, L.enddate) AS d
                  FROM (SELECT *
                             , CONCAT(tag, CAST(row_number() over (PARTITION BY tag ORDER BY enddate ASC) AS string)) AS rnend
                          FROM <your_db>.tmp_respaned_input) L
                       LEFT JOIN
                       (SELECT *
                             , CONCAT(tag, CAST(row_number() over (PARTITION BY tag ORDER BY startdate ASC) - 1 AS string)) AS rnend
                          FROM <your_db>.tmp_respaned_input) R
                       ON L.rnend = R.rnend) X
         WHERE d > 1 or d IS NULL) E
       ON S.rnlink = E.rnlink;



-- Print results
SELECT *
  FROM <your_db>.results
 ORDER BY startdate ASC;

#   results.accountid  results.provider results.los results.startdate       results.enddate
#1  123A               smith            7           2019-03-01 00:00:00.0   2019-03-08 00:00:00.0
#2  456B               rogers           1           2019-03-02 00:00:00.0   2019-03-03 00:00:00.0
#3  456B               daniels          5           2019-03-04 00:00:00.0   2019-03-09 00:00:00.0
#4  123A               smith            2           2019-03-10 00:00:00.0   2019-03-12 00:00:00.0
```

Comment: I give a try to solve it but it has become tricky due to third row in your table where start date is smaller then previous end  date of same group

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, please see comments in the code:

```
--configuration
set hive.cli.print.header=true;
set hive.execution.engine=tez;
set hive.mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution=false;
set mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution=false;
set hive.exec.parallel=true;
set hive.exec.parallel.thread.number=36;
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=true;
set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled=true;
set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.groupby.enabled=true;
set hive.map.aggr=true;

with example as (--this is your data example
select stack (9, '123A', 'smith', '2019-03-01 00:00:00', '2019-03-04 00:00:00',
'456B', 'rogers', '2019-03-02 00:00:00', '2019-03-03 00:00:00',
'123A', 'smith', '2019-03-03 00:00:00', '2019-03-06 00:00:00',
'123A', 'smith', '2019-03-07 00:00:00', '2019-03-08 00:00:00',
'456B', 'daniels', '2019-03-04 00:00:00', '2019-03-05 00:00:00',
'456B', 'daniels', '2019-03-06 00:00:00', '2019-03-09 00:00:00',
'123A', 'smith', '2019-03-10 00:00:00', '2019-03-12 00:00:00',
--I added one more case
'123A', 'smith', '2019-03-14 00:00:00', '2019-03-17 00:00:00',
'123A', 'smith', '2019-03-18 00:00:00', '2019-03-19 00:00:00'
) as (accountId, provider, startdate, enddate )
)

select --aggregate start and end dates for the whole case, count LOS 
       accountId, provider, datediff(max(enddate),min(startdate)) as los, min(startdate) startdate , max(enddate) enddate
from
(
select --distribute case_id across all records in the same case
       accountId, provider, startdate, enddate,
       last_value(case_id, true) over(partition by accountid, same_case_flag order by startdate ) as case_id --Bingo!!! we have case_id     
from
(
select --generate UUID as case_id if previous same_case_flag != current one or previous was NULL. 
       --One UUID will be generated for each new case
       accountId, provider, startdate, enddate, same_case_flag, 
       case when lag(same_case_flag) over(partition by accountid order by startdate) = same_case_flag 
              then NULL else java_method("java.util.UUID", "randomUUID") 
        end case_id      
from
(
select --calculate same case flag
       accountId, provider, startdate, enddate,
        case when  datediff(startdate,lag(enddate) over(partition by accountId order by startdate)) <=1    --startdate - prev_enddate                          
                   OR  
                   datediff(lead(startdate) over(partition by accountId order by startdate), enddate) <=1  --next_startdate-enddate
                then true else false 
         end as same_case_flag                  
  from example s
)s)s)s
group by accountId, provider, case_id
order by startdate;  --remove order by if not necessary to sppeed-up processing !!! I added it to get the same ordering as in your example
```

Result:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        VERTICES      STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Map 1 ..........   SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0
Reducer 2 ......   SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0
Reducer 3 ......   SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0
Reducer 4 ......   SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0
Reducer 5 ......   SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0
Reducer 6 ......   SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERTICES: 06/06  [==========================>>] 100%  ELAPSED TIME: 10.79 s
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK
accountid       provider        los     startdate       enddate
123A    smith   7       2019-03-01 00:00:00     2019-03-08 00:00:00
456B    rogers  1       2019-03-02 00:00:00     2019-03-03 00:00:00
456B    daniels 5       2019-03-04 00:00:00     2019-03-09 00:00:00
123A    smith   2       2019-03-10 00:00:00     2019-03-12 00:00:00
123A    smith   5       2019-03-14 00:00:00     2019-03-19 00:00:00
Time taken: 29.049 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)
```

Remove order to get rid of last reducer.

Depending on your date, probably for assigning case_id you can use `concat(accountid, rand())` or concat also startdate, or something like this instead of `randomUUID` if there are rear separate cases with the same accountid, but randomUUID is safer because it is always unique.

This approach does not use joins at all.