# When generating date series in HIVE, limit effective date out to TODAY

Tags: date, hive, hiveql

Some time back, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45278300/how-to-generate-date-series-in-hive-creating-table) was answered about generating date series in hive, meaning filling the days between an effective in and effective out dates (or start-end dates). I am wondering if from the same statement, you could limit the end date to TODAY, for those cases in which the end date might be 9999-12-21, being that an active record. Is it possible? How?

The suggested script in the question linked above is:

```
select  t.AccountNumber
       ,date_add (t.StartDate,pe.i)   as Day

from    Table1 t
        lateral view 
        posexplode(split(space(datediff(t.EndDate,t.StartDate)),' ')) pe as i,x
```

Comment: can you not put `case when ` like this - `case when t.EndDate='9999-12-31' then now() else t.EndDate end` to calculate EndDate in above sql?

Comment: Thank you @KoushikRoy. A couple of hours after publishing tried different approaches and finally it worked with a case when:
`CASE WHEN t.eff_out_y = '9999-12-31' THEN CURRENT_DATE()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pls use - `case when t.EndDate='9999-12-31' then current_date() else t.EndDate end`