# Get complete set of rows per group

Tags: sql, r, hive, data.table, tidyr

***Edit going to broaden this to include R tag***

Hello,

I have a table ordered by id and month similar to the one below except it has millions of `id's` and hundreds of `var` columns, the `month` column could be any month from 2023.  I need to fill in the missing months per id and add a column that indicates if the id was active in a particular month. It is assumed the `id` was inactive  if they do not have a record for a particular month in the table. The total number of rows in the desired table will be 12* distinct id's. I have also included my desired output for the sample input. For R solutions I prefer a `tidyverse` solution but `data.table` option will also work given it will be much faster I just may not be as proficient in modifying it. Any help is appreciated.

Here are the dputs for R

```
input =structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), month = c(202301L, 202304L, 202305L, 
202301L, 202302L, 202303L, 202304L, 202305L, 202306L, 202307L, 
202308L, 202309L, 202310L, 202311L, 202312L, 202307L, 202308L
), var1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L), var2 = 1:17), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L))

output = structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), month = c(202301L, 202302L, 
202303L, 202304L, 202305L, 202306L, 202307L, 202308L, 202309L, 
202310L, 202311L, 202312L, 202301L, 202302L, 202303L, 202304L, 
202305L, 202306L, 202307L, 202308L, 202309L, 202310L, 202311L, 
202312L, 202301L, 202302L, 202303L, 202304L, 202305L, 202306L, 
202307L, 202308L, 202309L, 202310L, 202311L, 202312L), var1 = c(1L, 
NA, NA, 2L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 17L, 
18L, NA, NA, NA, NA), var2 = c(1L, NA, NA, 2L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16L, 17L, NA, NA, NA, NA), active = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L))
```

Sample input:

```
+----+--------+------+------+
| id | month  | var1 | var2 |
+----+--------+------+------+
|  1 | 202301 |    1 |    1 |
|  1 | 202304 |    2 |    2 |
|  1 | 202305 |    3 |    3 |
|  2 | 202301 |    5 |    4 |
|  2 | 202302 |    6 |    5 |
|  2 | 202303 |    7 |    6 |
|  2 | 202304 |    8 |    7 |
|  2 | 202305 |    9 |    8 |
|  2 | 202306 |   10 |    9 |
|  2 | 202307 |   11 |   10 |
|  2 | 202308 |   12 |   11 |
|  2 | 202309 |   13 |   12 |
|  2 | 202310 |   14 |   13 |
|  2 | 202311 |   15 |   14 |
|  2 | 202312 |   16 |   15 |
|  3 | 202307 |   17 |   16 |
|  3 | 202308 |   18 |   17 |
+----+--------+------+------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+----+--------+------+------+--------+
| id | month  | var1 | var2 | active |
+----+--------+------+------+--------+
|  1 | 202301 |    1 |    1 |      1 |
|  1 | 202302 |      |      |      0 |
|  1 | 202303 |      |      |      0 |
|  1 | 202304 |    2 |    2 |      1 |
|  1 | 202305 |    3 |    3 |      1 |
|  1 | 202306 |      |      |      0 |
|  1 | 202307 |      |      |      0 |
|  1 | 202308 |      |      |      0 |
|  1 | 202309 |      |      |      0 |
|  1 | 202310 |      |      |      0 |
|  1 | 202311 |      |      |      0 |
|  1 | 202312 |      |      |      0 |
|  2 | 202301 |    5 |    4 |      1 |
|  2 | 202302 |    6 |    5 |      1 |
|  2 | 202303 |    7 |    6 |      1 |
|  2 | 202304 |    8 |    7 |      1 |
|  2 | 202305 |    9 |    8 |      1 |
|  2 | 202306 |   10 |    9 |      1 |
|  2 | 202307 |   11 |   10 |      1 |
|  2 | 202308 |   12 |   11 |      1 |
|  2 | 202309 |   13 |   12 |      1 |
|  2 | 202310 |   14 |   13 |      1 |
|  2 | 202311 |   15 |   14 |      1 |
|  2 | 202312 |   16 |   15 |      1 |
|  3 | 202301 |      |      |      0 |
|  3 | 202302 |      |      |      0 |
|  3 | 202303 |      |      |      0 |
|  3 | 202304 |      |      |      0 |
|  3 | 202305 |      |      |      0 |
|  3 | 202306 |      |      |      0 |
|  3 | 202307 |   17 |   16 |      1 |
|  3 | 202308 |   18 |   17 |      1 |
|  3 | 202309 |      |      |      0 |
|  3 | 202310 |      |      |      0 |
|  3 | 202311 |      |      |      0 |
|  3 | 202312 |      |      |      0 |
+----+--------+------+------+--------+
```

Comment: I don't use hive, but I guess there are some functions like generate_series in PostgreSQL.  This way, you should be able to produce your desired result. Maybe this question helps, it's similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45278300/how-to-generate-date-series-in-hive-creating-table

Comment: I see, if  I could generate a table with the id and series of months then I could use a join correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with ids as (
    select distinct id from T
), months as (
    -- assuming there's at least one active id every month
    select distinct month from T
    -- where month between '202301' and '202312'
)
select i.id, m.month, t.var1, t.var2,
    case when t.id is null then 1 else 0 end as active
from ids i cross join months m left outer join T t
    on t.id = i.id and t.month = m.month;
```

Honestly, I don't really know anything in particular about Hive but this is the general idea to "densifying" your results. The outputs for missing rows will be nulls.

Answer (score -1):

To add the missing months to your table, you can use the INSERT statement along with the SELECT statement that generates the missing months. Here’s an example that inserts the missing months into the DOCTOR_CHECKUP table:

```
INSERT INTO DOCTOR_CHECKUP (CHECKED_DATE)
SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2016-01-01', LEVEL - 1), 'MM-YYYY') MTH
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24
MINUS
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CHECKED_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY'), 'MM-YYYY')
FROM DOCTOR_CHECKUP;
```

This query inserts the missing months into the CHECKED_DATE column of the DOCTOR_CHECKUP table. You may need to adjust the column names and date format to match your table structure.

You can use a subquery to select the data from another column in the same table or a different table and include it in the INSERT statement. Here’s an example:

```
INSERT INTO DOCTOR_CHECKUP (CHECKED_DATE, ANOTHER_COLUMN)
SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2016-01-01', LEVEL - 1), 'MM-YYYY') MTH, ANOTHER_COLUMN
FROM ANOTHER_TABLE
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24
MINUS
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CHECKED_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY'), 'MM-YYYY'), ANOTHER_COLUMN
FROM DOCTOR_CHECKUP;
```

In this example, the data from the ANOTHER_COLUMN column in the ANOTHER_TABLE table is included in the INSERT statement. You can replace ANOTHER_TABLE with the name of the table that contains the column you want to include, and ANOTHER_COLUMN with the name of the column you want to include.

Comment: Are you sure this will work in a hive DB? Your commands look like they are written for an Oracle DB.

Comment: I don't think Hive supports the Connect By syntax